# What are the implications of allowing users to create stored procedures?

Tags: sql, security, stored-procedures

We are looking into a scenario where there might be huge performance gains to be had from having stored procedures specific to each situation over having generic code.

Currently the database is locked down.
It goes without saying that I intend to validate all untrusted input however I want to be aware of any/all risks and avoid where possible.

So what, if any, risks are **added** in a situation where some untrusted data slips through the net and ends up inside a stored procedure?

My instinct tells me it is a bad idea but I am unable to justify that currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree that its a bad idea. A good reason for using stored procedures is to prevent user generated input i.e. sql injection. I would recommend strongly against this in any public facing application. Maybe you could find some of your most frequent use cases and provide an option to select from those?

Answer (score 0):

One of the real benefit of using stored procedure is, it provides layer of security and easy to manage security at the stored procedure level.

Set aside security issue, I do not perceive any performance improvements if the query is poorly written. It may bring down the whole server.